# In Phabricator, how do I assign a parent to an existing task, changing it from task to sub-task

Tags: phabricator

It is not clear in the Phabricator interface or in documentation how I can assign a parent-task to an existing task. In trac I simply add a "parent" ticket number, and the task automatically becomes a sub-task of the new parent.

How do I accomplish the same thing in Phabricator so that an existing task becomes the child of another task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I accomplish this by going to the parent task and then "Edit Blocking Tasks."

Comment: Indeed! I had not realized that "Subtasks" and "Blocking tasks" are synonymous in Phabricator.

Comment: Relationships in Phabricator are expressed by edges. Subtasks or blocking tasks are UI words to convey the presence of such an edge between two tasks. You can get more information on the Edge concept at https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/using_edges/